# Python XLRD Get multiple cells/ table

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to read data from cell `a1` to `k100`. I know I can read each column with `.col_slice`, but I was wondering if anyone knew a way to read it all at once.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd` has not been updated since 2018. If you can, you should update to an active Python & Excel library, such as `openpyxl`. [Link to openpyxl tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells). This task is very easy with `openpyxl`.

> Accessing many cells.
>
> Ranges of cells can be accessed using slicing:

```py
>>> cell_range = ws['A1':'K100']
```